# s3cmd: Deleting files or folder does not work

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, s3cmd

`s3cmd s3://MYBUCKET/FOLDER` does not work. (folder is empty)
`s3cmd s3://MYBUCKET/FILE` does not work.

Output of both commands is "File FILE sucessfully deleted", yet the file remains on the bucket.

Deleting with the S3 Webinterface works just fine.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you have the syntax wrong (although it's possible you just typed it into this thing wrong).

From the [S3 Tools documentation](http://s3tools.org/usage) it looks like you want something like this:

```
s3cmd del s3://BUCKET/OBJECT
```

and

```
s3cmd del -r s3://BUCKET/FOLDER
```

Typically you need to use the -r, or recursive, flag to delete folders.

If that doesn't work, check that your permissions and keys are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
> s3cmd  ls s3://BucketName/foldername_prefix* |awk '{print $2}' | while read files; do s3cmd  rm -r $files; done
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (like using hudi format) even delete command like this does not work:

```
s3cmd rm s3://mybucket/myfileidontwant --force
```

Then the only solution is to create the file manually using s3cmd, and then run delete command.